# exiting "if" in a "while" loop in vbscript-QTP

Tags: vbscript, while-loop, qtp

I am stuck with a problem for exiting out of a while loop 
I have tried using break, Exit do

The algorithm for automated testcase goes as follows

```
while true
do some tasks
    if total >200 then 
       do some tasks 
       and 
       exit out of while loop if this condition reaches
    End if
wend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only exit point is on the `total > 200`

```
do
    do_some_tasks
    if total > 200 then
        do_total_related_tasks
    end if 
loop until total > 200
```

that can be simplified to

```
do
    do_some_tasks
loop until total > 200
do_total_related_tasks
```

For a more general, multiple exit point, the fastest option is the `exit do`

```
do
    do_some_tasks
    if total > 200 then
        do_total_related_tasks
        exit do
    end if 
    other_tasks
loop while true
```

Or, for a more general solution, use a variable

```
keepTesting = true
do
    do_some_always_tasks
    ' start to test conditions
    if keepTesting then if total > 200 then 
        do_total_related_tasks
        keepTesting = false
    end if 
    if keepTesting then if other_exit_condition then
        .....
        keepTesting = false
    end if 
    .....
loop while keepTesting
```

Or whatever other construction depending of the real problem.